# Can I define such an average norm of an infinite-dimensional vector?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppoes that there is an infinite-dimensional vector $x = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{\infty}\}$. Can I define such a norm
$$
\|x\| =  \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} x_k,
$$
which implies that the limit must exist.

I believe that it satisfies the definition of a norm, but I have never seen it in any contexts before. Is this norm properly defined?

Comment: Do you at least want absolute values inside the sum? I suppose otherwise you could restrict to nonnegative sequences.

Comment: The problem is definiteness. If $(x_k)\in \ell^1$, then $\|x\|=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N|x_k|=0$.

Comment: I see. The average norm is not well-defined! For a non-zero vector the norm may also be zero, which contradicts the definition of a norm. Thank you all for your useful comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This average norm is not well-defined! For a non-zero vector the norm may also be zero, which contradicts the definition of a norm. For example, the norm of $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$ is zero but it is a non-zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_k=k$ for all $k$, then

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} x_k= \frac{N+1}{2},$$

so $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} x_k$ does not exist.

Comment: Right, but your example only confirms that $x_k = k$ does not in the "average norm" space (if exists). There are also many vectors belonging to this space as long as the limit in the norm exists, e.g., $x_k = 5+\frac{1}{k}$.